# How much can a feruchemist store in a metal mind?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire, wax-wayne-novels

I'm just about to finish the second *Mistborn* book, and I'm wondering:

> Sazed now has eight of his metalminds lodged inside him.

Is the amount he stores in them going to be limited? If so is it related to the efficiency of the feruchemist? The it size of the metalmind?

Comment: I'm mainly musing on whether he'll ever need new metal minds of the same kind, or he can go 'metalless'?

Comment: this is explored in the third book... are you sure you want an answer?

Comment: Does it spoil the plot, or is it seperate from it? I asked this (instead of other questions) as I thought it wouldn't be too plot specific.

Comment: It's addressed almost as soon as Sazed shows up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have the book with me, so I'm lacking a specific quote, but Sazed alludes to his rings not being able to hold very much and implies that a bigger ring (or armlet like his Copperminds) would be able to store more.

So yes, its dependent on the size of the metal-mind.

Actually, I think at one point purity of the metal is mentioned as being close enough to use a a metal mind, but there was no comment as to efficiency for this.

Comment: You're right (as far as I remember) purity and size are the determining factors.